# Problema con decimales en JavaScript con c#

Tags: javascript, c#

quería consultarles cómo puedo controlar los decimales en HTML-JavaScript.
Me explico, estoy haciendo una aplicación con Asp.net y en la definición de mis clases de C# tengo campos declarados como tipo: **decimal**
y en mi función JavaScript realizo la siguiente operación:

```
vPorcGanancia.onchange = function () {
    if (vPrecioCompra.value > 0 && vPorcGanancia.value > 0)            
        document.getElementById("PrecioVenta").value = ((parseInt(vPrecioCompra.value) * parseInt(vPorcGanancia.value)) / 100) + parseInt(vPrecioCompra.value);
};
```

La consulta es:

1. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se ingrese y muestre solamente 2 decimales?

   @Html.Editor("PorcGanancia", null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number" } })
2. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que realice las operaciones con números decimales? Ya que por el momento estoy usando el `**parseInt**`

También les comento que en mi clase tengo el campo como:

```
[Display(Name = "Porcentaje de ganancia")]
[Required]
public decimal PorcGanancia { get; set; }
```

y en la tabla SQL:

```
[PorcGanancia] decimal(6,3)  NOT NULL,
```

Comment: para trabajar con decimales tienes la función [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo el mismo problema con el parseFloat javascript te pondra los decimales con puntos en vez de con comas. Al ser un punto C# lo coge como miles en vez de decimal y no lo espresa bien. Por lo tanto mi solucion fue poner el input como campo requerido en la entitie de esta manera.

```
  [Required]
  [Column(TypeName = "double(18, 2)")]
  [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]+(\,[0-9][0-9]?)?", ErrorMessage = "El campo tiene que ser decimal, ejemplo 500,50")]

  public double Kilos { get; set; }
```

De esta manera la entidad sabe que ese campoes requerido, con el Column le decimos como queremos la base de datos y encima tenemos una RegularExpression para decimales con las comas para que C# nos lo coja bien a la ora de operar.

Comment: Buena idea estimado, voy a seguir tu consejo, muchas gracias...